# arraylist isEmpty() doubts and questions

Tags: java, list, arraylist

i have question.
I want to check my ararylist of a specify index whether is the index is empty.
User may have input store like 7 items into my arraylist(index 0 to 6).
So i want to check for index 7 whether it is empty, if it is empty i will loop back to my RoomSelection().

Im using the roomInfo(4+ xx)IsEmpty.

Is the IsEmpty command juz for checking the whole arraylist whether is empty?

If it is to check for the whole arraylist , what other method can i use to check if index 7 is empty?

```
for (int x = 0; x < (Integer) roomInfo.get(2); x++) {//start of number of room loop(to check how many rooms user input)

    for (int i = 0; i < (Integer) roomInfo.get(4 + xx); i++) { //start of number of add-on loop(to check how many add-on user input)


        System.out.println("addOns array contains what? : " + addOns);    // for my own reference
        System.out.println("Enter Add-On option");
        ao2 = input.nextInt();
        while (ao2 > 4) {
            System.out.println("Please enter again! Choose only option 1 to 4");
            ao2 = input.nextInt();
        }
        addOnOpt = addOn[ao2 - 1];
        addOns.add(addOnOpt);
        addOnPrice = priceAdd[ao2 - 1];
        addOns.add(addOnPrice);
        System.out.println("Enter quantity required for Add-On option " + (i + 1) + ": ");
        quan = input.nextInt();
        addOns.add(quan);
        xx += 3;
        System.out.println(" not null yet");
        if ((roomInfo.isEmpty(4 + xx) == true) {//if condition to check whether is the arrayllist of position is not null
            System.out.println("null!");
            xx = 0;
            Selection();
        }


    }// end of add-on loop

}//end of number of room loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eighth item (index 7) will be "empty" if the ArrayList has seven or fewer items, or you added `null` in index 7; you'll need to test both of those conditions:

```
if(roomInfo.size() < 8 || roomInfo.get(7) == null) {
    // index 7 is "empty"
}
```

Comment: if my index 7 has nothing , i juz need to do if(roomInfo.size()<4+xx) this will do right?

Answer (score 3):

`isEmpty()` returns true if there is no item in the list.

To know if there is a 7th item, check the size of the list (is it superior or equal to 7) using the `size()` method.

Answer (score 1):

> isEmpty() 
>             Tests if this list has no elements.
>
> "If it is to check for the whole arraylist , what other method can i
>   use to check if index 7 is empty?"

Let's say you have this:

```
ArrayList<abc> list=new ArrayList<abc>();
```

`abc.size()` returns the number of elements in the list.
If you want to check if the element at index 8 exists, the easy way would be to see if  size returns at least 9.
So:

```
int indexExists=8;
if(abc.size()>indexExists)
  //do whatever with abc.get(indexExists)
else
  //abc.get(8) will return a null pointer exception
```

Check this link for other methods on ArrayList http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Answer (score 1):

`isEmpty()` function on arraylist is to check whether the whole arraylist is empty or not.
You can probably take up each elements and check.

Answer (score 0):

IsEmpty() method only check if the list has no elements.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#isEmpty%28%29

As elements are added to an ArrayList, its capacity grows automatically, so to check the 7th position, check the size of the list with .size()